# Manipular un UserForm en Excel con Python

Tags: python, excel, vba

Tengo un botón en una hoja de excel que llama a un formulario con varias cosas como radio buttons, listbox, etc.

Estoy buscando la manera de manipular los comboboxes dentro del formulario con un script en Python pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

He estado jugando con xlwings pero solo he podido poner datos en la las celdas de excel no en los comboboxes dentro de un formulario.

Gracias.

Comment: Hola DanielV. Bienvenido a [es.so]. El idioma oficial del sitio es el español por lo que has de traducir la pregunta. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Un saludo